# How to add space between words after parsing with DOMParser?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, domparser

Lets say the `input` to the below code is `"<strong>In the</strong><br><strong>following questions</strong>"` then the output will be 
**In thefollwing questions.**
How can we have the space between words?like **In the follwing questions.**

```
 (new DOMParser).parseFromString(input, "text/html").documentElement.textContent
```

Comment: Will the input always follow that kind of format? Can you make any guarantees about the format of the input?

Comment: It is simple text that might contains equality signs  like "age <10", dashes...with html tags like <p> <strong><br>...